# implement rotating downloadable templates in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, templates, download, rotation

Look at : http://in.yahoo.com... In this you can see a rotating images(along with text).
And on click of this image...a server side code will get execute.

Can anybody tell me how can I implement the same in asp.net 2.0

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That's what's normally called a "Carousel" and would be implemented in JavaScript. Your preferred JavaScript library probably has a few plugins to handle that already (jQuery, YUI, etc), or you could probably create something using the Animations tools in the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit.